# angular constructor parameters @optional vs question mark usage

Tags: angular, typescript

Angular2 i can use both @optional or ? to denote the optional parameters in a constructor.I tried both and it looks similar.
What is the difference between them?

Comment: can you please give me any example showing use of `@` ?

Comment: i guess the '?' safe operator is mostly used in template not in constructors

Comment: @PardeepJain`constructor(@Optional() public engine:Engine) {}`

Comment: @RahulSingh thanks, but `?` can also be used in template as safe navigation but in constructor we can use it as assign optional parameter in typescript.

Comment: ya i told the same mostly used in templates , in  constructor there comes a concept of Angular DI and optional i guess uses that to check the dependecy and inject null

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`@Optional` marks the **dependency as optional**, thus injector will not raise an exception even if service provider for the dependency is not defined.

`?` is a Typescript symbol which marks the **function parameter as optional**, so it's purpose is different from `@Optional`.

If you use `?` in place of `@Optional` the Injector will still try to resolve dependency and if it can't it will raise an exception.

```
class Engine {}

@Directive({
  selector: 'child-directive'
})
class ChildDirective {
  constructor(@Optional() @Host() os:OtherService, @Optional() @Host() hs:HostService, public engine?: Engine){
    console.log("os is null", os);
    console.log("hs is NOT null", hs);
    console.log(this.engine); 
  }
}
```

This will raise exception if Engine service wasn't defined

```
EXCEPTION: No provider for Engine! (ChildDirective -> Engine)
```

[Here is plunkr demo code](https://embed.plnkr.co/jEZISqAksYWdaaBTFGd0/).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know optional parameters were introduced to TypeScript in 2.0 which was released about a year ago. Angular was started more than a year earlier.
I assume `@Optional()` was introduced because there was no language support for optional parameters yet.

Comment: Where did I say that? With `@Optional()` DI just passes `null` when it doesn't have a matching provider.